# Changing Android adb debug settings programmatically from recovery

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I'm trying to set up 60 Galaxy Tab 2 devices, by flashing CyanogenMod and then gapps onto each one. Unfortunately, at the moment I need some manual intervention on each one, which is annoying.

I can programmatically turn each one on and boot it into recovery mode, and then flash the CM ROM. It then automatically reboots the tablet, though, and I can't touch it after that because the default bootup doesn't have adb debugging turned on. I thus have to turn it back off, or boot it into recovery mode manually, before the next step.

What I would really like to do is to use adb while it's in recovery mode to turn on USB debugging, so that when it reboots, I'll be able to get to it. Ideally I'd just change a setting (use SQLite3 to change something somewhere?), but I could if necessary rebuild the CM11 zip to incorporate the setting somehow. I think I will need to turn on debugging, and also add the computer's RSA fingerprint so that it's allowed to talk to the device.

Any idea on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I could if necessary rebuild the CM11

A possible way for this option is to set `ro.debuggable=1` in [build/core/main.mk](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_build/blob/stable/cm-11.0/core/main.mk#L347) even for user builds. However, please note that that could lead to security breach as USB debugging is not meant to be used by normal end users.

Comment: Thanks. I've now hit the problem that I can't build the Tab 2 (p3110) CM11 tree... I can build it for my Nexus 4 (mako), so I know I'm not doing anything drastically wrong.